# numpyro.render_model cannot be found

Tags: python, bayesian, pyro.ai, numpyro

I am working with the Bayesian models in NumPyro. It is a relatively new library. I tried to visualize my model by following the Numpyro manual: http://num.pyro.ai/en/latest/tutorials/model_rendering.html

My code returns:

> "module 'numpyro' has no attribute 'render_model'"

I was wondering if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong. The Google search has not returned any relevant results.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

That particular feature has not been incorporated into a release as of this writing (v0.6.0). To use it, one would need to install the package from the GitHub source. E.g.,

```
pip install numpyro@git+https://github.com/pyro-ppl/numpyro
```

For those with Conda, a minimal environment would be

**numpyro.yaml**

```yaml
name: numpyro
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - tqdm
  - jax
  - pip
  - pip:
    - numpyro@git+https://github.com/pyro-ppl/numpyro
```